# How can I define index on inherited fields in MongoDB with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a persistent class that extends a parent where some of its fields are defined. With Spring Data Mongo, I can use the `@Indexed` annotation on persistent fields to create index on the corresponding Collection. However, in the case of inherited fields, I can only access them through the parent class. I could probably put the annotation there but I don't want to create index for a every Collection extending the parent class. Can I potentially use `@CompoundIndex` (with single value) to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some local testing, I found out that, yes, I can use `@CompoundIndex` to workaround this issue.